# Confusion matrix in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, confusion-matrix

How can I get a confusion matrix using specific columns in two different rasters in ArcGIS ? I have one raster of risk classes 1,2,3,4 and another raster of land cover A, B, C,D. I am looking for a matrix showing number of cell count for each land cover in each risk class.

Comment: You mean this? http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis10-functionality-matrix.pdf you did say "confusion" matrix...!!!

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote!

Comment: The SpatialAnalyst extension does have a [Compute Confusion Matrix](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/compute-confusion-matrix.htm) tool (perhaps only 10.4?), you may want to start there if you hadn't looked at it

Comment: Mine is 10.3, and looks like it does not have that tool. Thanks for the update for newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tool you want is not [Compute Confusion Matrix](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/compute-confusion-matrix.htm) as it is mainly used for accuracy assessment to compare the classified map with ground truth data. The following I quote from the help above:

> Computes a confusion matrix based on errors of omission and
>   commission, then derives a kappa index of agreement between the
>   classified map and data that is considered to be ground truth.
>
> This tool uses the outputs from the Create Accuracy Assessment Points
>   tool or the Update Accuracy Assessment Points tool.

The tool you need is [Tabulate Area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm). Tabulate area is used to calculate the area of zones within each another zone. So in your case you may use the land cover data as input data and the risk class as zone data. Then the tool will calculate the area of each land cover within each risk zone. Finally:

```
the number of cells/pixels (in each risk zone) = total area/cell size (pixel area)
```